# Micronaut Web-sockets Client Session errors

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, websocket, micronaut

So I have been trying to implement websockets based on the examples given on this example https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-websocket-maven-java.html  on the sverer side . I have a JavaFX client that uses the native java websocket API to connect to the server . The issue is I can't or I seem to fail to keep my client sessions alive on the server side , after connecting on javafx I get `INFO: onClose:statusCode- 1011`  after 5 seconds .

on the severe I have been tracking the sessions so , the session immediately closes , so I have started to think that its my client that has problems so I ended up using okhttp lib for this ,but I keep on getting the same issue of my sessions not living longer or expiring very early before any message can even be sent, below I have shared the client code and server code I have been testing with , so please can anyone help me on this if I am missing the point or something .

Yes , I have tried to look up for a solution on the server side to keep the session alive but you know Micronaut docs are also very shallow In practical solutions to our problems.

```java
// MyWebsockets.java  the server side
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.security.annotation.Secured;
import io.micronaut.security.rules.SecurityRule;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketBroadcaster;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketSession;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnClose;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnMessage;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnOpen;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.ServerWebSocket;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
@ServerWebSocket ("/ws/chat/{tail}/{logs}")
public class MyWebsockets {

    
    public final  WebSocketBroadcaster          broadcaster;
    

    private final Map<String, WebSocketSession> sessions        = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public MyWebsockets (WebSocketBroadcaster broadcaster) {
        this.broadcaster = broadcaster;
        
    }

    @OnOpen
    public Publisher<String> onOpen (String tail, String logs, WebSocketSession session) {

        System.out.println("onOpen: " + session.getId());
        sessions.put(session.getId(), session);
        System.out.println("onOpen: " + sessions.size());

        
        return broadcaster.broadcast(new JSONObject()
                        .put("type", "joined")
                        .put("success", true)
                        .put("logs", logs)
                        .put("tail", tail).toString()
                , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

    }

    @OnMessage
    public Publisher<String> onMessage (String tail, String logs, String message, WebSocketSession session) {
        System.out.println("onOpen: " + message);
        return broadcaster.broadcast(String.format("[%s] %s", logs, message),  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }

    @OnClose
    public Publisher<String> onClose (String tail, String logs, WebSocketSession session) {
        System.out.println("[onClose] " + tail + " " + logs  + session.getId());
        sessions.remove(session.getId());
        
        return broadcaster.broadcast(String.format("[%s] Leaving %s!", logs, tail), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaFX client code :

```java
public static void main (String [] s){

new Thread(() -> {

            ws = HttpClient
                    .newHttpClient()
                    .newWebSocketBuilder().connectTimeout(Duration.of(30, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                    .buildAsync(URI.create("ws://" + finalUrl +"/ws/chat/room/four"), new WebSocketClient())

                    .join();

            ws.sendText("hi",true);
            while (true) {
            }

        }).start();

}
[...]


private static class WebSocketClient implements WebSocket.Listener {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebSocketClient.class.getName());
        @Override
        public void onOpen (WebSocket webSocket) {
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(webSocket);
            WebSockets.IS_ONLINE = Boolean.TRUE;
            logger.info("onOpen: " + webSocket);
        }


        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onText (WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last) {
            WebSockets.IS_ONLINE = Boolean.TRUE;
            logger.info("onText received " + data);
            System.out.println("onText received " + data);
            
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onText(webSocket, data, last);
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onPing (WebSocket webSocket, ByteBuffer message) {
            System.out.println("onPing received " + message);
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onPing(webSocket, message);
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onPong (WebSocket webSocket, ByteBuffer message) {
            System.out.println("onPong received " + message);
            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onPong(webSocket, message);
        }

        @Override
        public CompletionStage<?> onClose (WebSocket webSocket, int statusCode, String reason) {

            logger.info("onClose:statusCode- " + statusCode);
            WebSockets.IS_ONLINE = Boolean.FALSE;

            return WebSocket.Listener.super.onClose(webSocket, statusCode, reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError (WebSocket webSocket, Throwable error) {
            logger.info("Bad day! " + webSocket.toString());
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onError(webSocket, error);


        }

        
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], e.g. code without redacted `...` blocks in it, that could be run via copy and paste.  Your client code doesn't appear to have any JavaFX in it, so I am guessing JavaFX is (currently) irrelevant to the question and it is OK to keep it that way if your issue isn't really related to JavaFX usage.

Comment: Oracle [provides a WebSocket example with JavaFX](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/BinaryWebSocket/binaryWebSocket.html).  WebSocket is a low level API.  Consider using a higher level API instead, e.g. either using a built-to-purpose chat API or a generic messaging API such as Stomp.  Baeldung provides some info on using Stomp in Spring servers and clients, in [Intro to WebSockets with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring) and [A Java Client for a WebSockets API](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client).

Comment: Also, if you need it [info on Stomp](https://stomp.github.io/) and the [Stomp specifcation](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html) so that you can understand what it is.

Comment: Another example of integrating [websockets and JavaFX](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test), based on Tyrus (the predecessor to official JDK/JEE WebSocket implementations).  Here is a [console chat client and server](https://github.com/fmbenhassine/web-socket-lab) using the same web socket framework.